# Why do React Components pass down context and props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on `React.js` code that is not my own and I'm new to React.
I hate React, but I think that might be because I don't understand it, so now I need to learn and understand it.

What is the deal with context and props?

#### For example `baobab-react`:

Here the idea is ["Rooting our top-level component"](https://github.com/Yomguithereal/baobab-react/blob/v2/docs/higher-order.md#rooting-our-top-level-component)...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {root} from 'baobab-react/higher-order';
import tree from './state';

// We will write this component later
import List from './list.jsx';

// Creating our top-level component
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <List />;
  }
}

// Let's bind the component to the tree through the `root` higher-order component
const RootedApp = root(App, tree);

// Rendering the app
render(<RootedApp />, document.querySelector('#mount'));
```

And then ["Branching our list"](https://github.com/Yomguithereal/baobab-react/blob/v2/docs/higher-order.md#branching-our-list)...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {branch} from 'baobab-react/higher-order';

class List extends Component {
  render() {

    // Thanks to the branch, our colors will be passed as props to the component
    const colors = this.props.colors;

    function renderItem(color) {
      return <li key={color}>{color}</li>;
    }

    return <ul>{colors.map(renderItem)}</ul>;
  }
}

// Branching the component by mapping the desired data to cursors
export default branch(List, {
  cursors: {
    colors: ['colors']
  }
});
```

Why cant I just include the data store per component and interact with it directly?

Comment: Because the single source of truth (the single central store) is easier to deal with.

Comment: React is one-way. If a user interaction on a sub-component changes the application state, that change needs to propagate through the action controller to update the store and trigger a new render. The cool thing about React is that it only actually re-renders the elements (if any) that change between state transitions, so calling `render` on the top-level component is actually very fast.

Comment: I get that a central store is easier to deal with and I agree 100%. But I believe this can be done be connecting each component to the central store. Passing the reference to the store from component to subcomponent seems odd. Or am I missing something? Is this reference to the store somehow manipulated on the way? Or is this somehow related to other components knowing that the store has changed?

Comment: It is a missing piece to React. Sometimes - but very rarely - you need to reach back up into the single source of truth to cause a bigger change. React devs discovered the need for this a few years into it and made Redux. Yes, it's another thing to learn, but it's far better than frankensteining it all together into one library that would be occasionally used.